# Using ProtoBuf-net to deseriailize a derived type (dictionary) does not properly set object fields

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net, deep-copy

I'm trying to serialize and then deserialize an object whose class derives from a `Dictionary<string,int>` with a string member field.

```
    public class TempClass : Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        public string Version;

        public TempClass() { }
    }
```

I've written a unit test to capture the problem that I'm running into: the member field is not set when either serializing or deserializing (to/from a byte[]) with protobuf-net. This test fails in the final `Assert` when validating that the deserialized `Version` is properly set. It is always set to `null` instead of the proper `"someVersion"`.

```
    [TestClass]
    public class serializationTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            string newVersion = "someVersion";

            TempClass original = new TempClass()
            {
                {"a", 2},
                {"b", 3},
                {"c", 1},
            };
            original.Version = newVersion;

            byte[] serialized = Serialize(original);

            TempClass deserialized = Deserialize(serialized);

            // Validate
            foreach (var pair in original)
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(deserialized.ContainsKey(pair.Key));
                Assert.AreEqual(pair.Value, deserialized[pair.Key]);
            }

            Assert.AreEqual(newVersion, original.Version, "original mapping version not set correctly");
            Assert.AreEqual(newVersion, deserialized.Version, "deserialized version doesn't match");
        }

        private static TempClass Deserialize(byte[] serialized)
        {
            TempClass deserialized;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Write(serialized, 0, serialized.Length);
                ms.Position = 0;
                deserialized = Serializer.Deserialize<TempClass>(ms);
            }
            return deserialized;
        }

        private static byte[] Serialize(TempClass mapping)
        {
            byte[] serialized;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(ms, mapping);
                serialized = ms.ToArray();
            }
            return serialized;
        }
    }
```

I've already attempted the same work with the `BinaryFormatter` and also the `DataContractSerializer` to no avail. Can someone please help me spot where I've goofed that causes this test to fail?

**Followup question:** If instead I redefine the `TempClass` like this, the constructor is always called instead of setting the member field properly to the original `Version`. How can I deserialize without the constructor creating a new `Version` and instead just copy the original one?

```
    public class TempClass : Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        public string Version;

        public TempClass() 
        { 
            Version = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for easy usable test. That save time.

Answer (score 0):

May be this effect related to internal realization of serialization of IDictionary types in protobuf.
You can add version data in dictionary or rewrite yours dto object like this sample.
If you use this data object, it will fix your test:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class TempClass 
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Dictionary<string, int> data;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Version;

    public TempClass() { }
}
```

The third way is to write your own serialization.

Comment: This would work if `TempClass` didn't have to also be `IEnumerable`, `IDictionary`, etc. However, changing the type of `TempClass` will break a lot of existing code, so this solution won't work unless I also implement all the interfaces of `Dictionary`, as well.

Comment: You didn`t need to implement interfaces, you could just wrap your data to dto object before serialize it.

Comment: The fact remains that if I use your version of the class in my unit test then the code does not compile. I need code that compiles **AND** passes the test.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ProtoContract]
public class TempClass 
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Dictionary<string, int> data;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Version;

    public TempClass() { }
}

[TestClass]
public class serializationTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        string newVersion = "someVersion";

        TempClass original = new TempClass()
        {
            data = new Dictionary<string,int>
            {
                {"a", 2},
                {"b", 3},
                {"c", 1},
            },
            Version = newVersion
        };

        byte[] serialized = Serialize(original);

        TempClass deserialized = Deserialize(serialized);

        // Validate
        foreach (var pair in original.data)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(deserialized.data.ContainsKey(pair.Key));
            Assert.AreEqual(pair.Value, deserialized.data[pair.Key]);
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(newVersion, original.Version, "original mapping version not set correctly");
        Assert.AreEqual(newVersion, deserialized.Version, "deserialized version doesn't match");
    }

    private static TempClass Deserialize(byte[] serialized)
    {
        TempClass deserialized;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ms.Write(serialized, 0, serialized.Length);
            ms.Position = 0;
            deserialized = Serializer.Deserialize<TempClass>(ms);
        }
        return deserialized;
    }

    private static byte[] Serialize(TempClass mapping)
    {
        byte[] serialized;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, mapping);
            serialized = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return serialized;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've modified the test in order to pass with a new implementation. This is breaking the contract that the unit test was originally written to enforce. I'm looking for an answer to the original question. Not an answer to your own question.

Comment: Oh.. great. You ask for soulutions - i give you a ways. You ask for code - i give you a code. Than you downvote. 
So, any way I supose this will helpful for some one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ProtoContract(UseProtoMembersOnly = true, IgnoreListHandling = true)]`
 instead of `[ProtoContract]` solves the problem for me.

This will prevent protobuf-net to serialize the class with dictionary rules. (See [this](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/wiki/Attributes))

Here is an example.

```
[ProtoContract(UseProtoMembersOnly = true, IgnoreListHandling = true)]
public class ProtobufTest<T, P> : IDictionary<T, P>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private readonly Dictionary<T, P> _dataset;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name;

    private ProtobufTest(Dictionary<T, P> dataset, string name)
    {
        _dataset = dataset ?? new Dictionary<T, P>();
        Name = name;
    }
    public ProtobufTest(string name) : this(new Dictionary<T, P>(), name) { }
    private ProtobufTest() : this(null, string.Empty) {}

    //
    // IDictionary implementation is omitted.
    //
}
```

Here is an example unit test.

```
    [Test]
    public void ProtobufTestNameSerializeDeserialize()
    {
        ProtobufTest<double, double> t = new ProtobufTest<double, double>("233");
        ProtobufTest<double, double> d;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, t, PrefixStyle.Base128);
            ms.Position = 0;
            d = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<ProtobufTest<double, double>>(ms, PrefixStyle.Base128);
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(t.Name, d.Name);
    }
```

(These codes are examples ONLY)